Inherit the class code, but NOT the layout and design of a Delphi form?
I have a form TMyForm. Now I want to make a new form TNewForm which inherits TMyForm's code (.pas), but not the layout and design (.dfm). Is that possible?
Since the new form has a completely different layout and design, but need to reuse the code from TMyForm.

You need to introduce a new base class inheriting from TForm, where you add the common code for your forms. Then inherit from this new class your TMyForm and TNewForm.

What do you mean "the codes"? The methods? The properties? The fields? Some actual data? There are different ways to do each of these. In general, what @DelphiCoder says above is appropriate. TForm is just a class. You can inherit from it to create your own derived class, put whatever you want in it, then inherit from that child to a grandchild to extend it further. Just beware that working with derived forms in the IDE is problematic.

@DavidSchwartz, What I mean the methods, fields and properties in the class(all in the .pas file), but not those in .dfm file.

@DelphiCoder, you solution is feasible, but I hope to make things simpler.

@alancc I have a feeling you don't understand purpose of *.dfm file properly. The purpose of *.dfm files is not to determine if certain component exists on the form or not but instead to streamline the process of initialising the initial state of these components when form is created. Whenever you place a component on the form during design-time a new field is added to the form class that has the same name and type as the component that has been placed on the form. So if you inherit from this class they you are also inheriting all those component fields as well. ...

@alancc ... That is why you should follow Delphi Coder's suggestion about creating a common base class and then inheriting both of your forms from it.

You need to redesign your application to separate the business logic from the user interface. You can then use that business logic anywhere you like without worrying about where the UI comes from.

@alancc your form is a class derived from a TForm. That's only PART of what's in the .pas file. Simply thinking that the "form" is in the .dfm file and that everything in the .pas file constitues "the rest" of the form is flat-out wrong. You seem unaware that an entire form can be created in code, and that no .dfm file is needed. The three pillars of OOP include: encapsulation, inheritance, and polymorphism. Forms employ ALL of these attributes. You need to create a BASE CLASS, with or without a .dfm file, and then create DERIVED class and add whatever you want to it.

the Dfm can be readily detached by adding whitespace to switch in implementation. Many use a dot here.
   {.$R *.DFM}

The Ide needs to be restarted to lose the DFM. Also we use class methods of the SharedEvent class.
unit SharedEvents;

interface

uses
 System.Classes,
  Vcl.Controls;

type
  TStringEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject; s: string) of Object;
  TCustomEvents = class(TComponent)
  public
    Class function WhoAmI(Sender: TObject): string;
    Class procedure WhoAmIProc(Sender: TObject; var str: string);
  end;

implementation

{.$R *.dfm}

{ TCustomEvents }

class function TCustomEvents.WhoAmI(Sender: TObject): string;
begin
  Result := Sender.ClassName;
  if Sender is Tcomponent then
    Result := TComponent(Sender).Name + ' ' + Result
  else
    Result := 'No Name on ' + Result;
end;

class procedure TCustomEvents.WhoAmIProc(Sender: TObject;var str: string);
begin
  str := WhoAmI(Sender);
end;

end.

Access the class methods of CustomEvents in the Newform code. Notice the procedure uses a TStringEvent which was typed in above CustomEvents.
implementation

uses
  sharedEvents;

procedure TMainEvent.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Caption := TCustomEvents.WhoAmI(Sender);
end;

procedure TMainEvent.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  var s: string;
  TCustomEvents.WhoAmIProc(Sender,s);
  Caption := s;
end;

Putting events in a module allows a controller. Hooking up the events allows the views, referenced components in forms, to be updated as needed. It is shared like DataModule only populated with controllers and models and yes a baseform. The codebase is centralized and since it reads and sends messages to referenced controls the need to add forms to uses clause is reduced and a MyFormUnit in uses not needed.  It's easier to build as a form first and convert later vs building from scratch.

This is a classic example of how to break encapsulation when you don't understand how inheritance works. This might work, but it's a horrible solution.
